# How to delete own Telegram's group/channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-group

I've created a group and a channel on Telegram, but they're no longer in use.

I can leave a group/channel, but it doesn't solve my problem.

How do I remove them completely?

---

I've tried *Telegram Desktop* v1.5.4 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it by following these steps (in Telegram Desktop v1.5.4 on Windows):

1. Go to *View channel/group info* by clicking a triple-dot icon.
2. Go to *Manage Channel/Group* by clicking a triple-dot icon.
3. Click on *Channel Info*.
4. *Delete* channel/group.

On Android app (Telegram X), the following steps should work:

1. Tap on the channel/group title.
2. Go to *Manage Channel/Group* by clicking a pen icon.
3. Choose *Destroy* channel/group by clicking a triple-dot icon.

Related question on Quora: [How do I delete an abandoned Telegram channel?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-delete-an-abandoned-Telegram-channel).